# Check product in range postive or negative

Tags: c++, algorithm

You are given two integers A and B. Your task is to determine if the product of the integers A,A+1,A+2,...,B is positive, negative or zero.

Input
The input contains two integers A and B (−109≤A≤B≤109).

Output
If the product is positive, print Positive. If it is negative, print Negative. If it is zero, print Zero.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    long long num1,num2;
    bool check=false;
    long long  count=0;

    cin>>num1>>num2;
    while(num1<=num2)
    {
        if(num1==0)
        {
            check=true;
            break;
        }
        if(num1<0)
        {
            count++;
            num1++;
        }
        else
        {
            num1++;
        }
    }
    if(count%2==0&&check==false)
    {
        cout<<"Positive";
    }
    else if(count%2!=0&&check==false)
    {
        cout<<"Negative";
    }
    else
        cout<<"Zero";



    return 0;
}
```

how can i get better algoritm which not take much time and without overflow if someone have better idea to check if the product is postive or negative or zero ?

Comment: Hint: it's only a matter of how many numbers there are and their signs, or whether the range includes zero.  (Think about what happens when you multiply two, three, four, five, ... negative numbers. Now multiply with a positive number. Do you see a pattern?)

Comment: @molbdnilo: Well, *sometimes* how many matters.

Comment: Got it @ScottHunter.. my bad.

Comment: You don't need to loop from A to B to determine how many values are between A and B, nor to determine if that range includes 0 or not.

Comment: @molbdnilo I  guess i don't understand what you mean yet :( can you explain your answer more

Comment: Break the problem up into 3 cases and solve them separately: 1) `0<A` 2) `A<=0<=B` 3) `B<0`. Each one can be solved in `O(1)` time and memory (i.e. no loops.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably remember from when you were little that the product of two positive numbers is positive.
You probably also remember that the product of two negative numbers is positive, and that the product of one negative and one positive number is negative.

In other words, multiplying by a positive number has no effect on the sign, and multiplying by a negative number turns + into - and - into +.

From this, you can deduce first of all that you can ignore the positive part of the range, as it has no effect on the result.

You can also deduce that the product of *three* negative numbers is the product of one positive number and one negative number, so it is negative.
You can further deduce that the product of *four* negative numbers is the product of two positive number, so it is positive.

Now you can discover a very simple pattern, and figure out how to solve this problem without multiplying any numbers at all - you only need to care about

1. Is there a zero involved?
2. How many negative numbers are there?

Working out the details left as an exercise.
(If your solution is more than a couple of lines long, you're on the wrong track.)